# roscd/roslaunch cannot find the package that be built recently

Tags: ros, roslaunch, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.everyone.I put some packages in my workspace ~/catkin_ws/src recently and then executed the conmmand catkin_make in ~/catkin_ws as usual.But I cannot use roscd to open the new build packages while old packages works. In my ~/.bashrc. I put `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`  and `source /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` in the end.Iguess if I donot put the last setup.bash I cannot roscd any packages in ~/catkin_ws. What makes me confused is that some packages can be opened using roscd while the new one cannot. Could any one please give me a solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272856/roscd/roslaunch-cannot-find-the-package-that-be-built-recently/) by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil333](https://answers.ros.org/users/21017/phil333/) on 2017-10-12**:
did you try running source "~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" in your current terminal? Otherwise try to close everything and open a new consol.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-12**:
Thanks for your reply.I put `source /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` in my ~/.bashrc, so I guess when I open a new terminal it can source automatically,right? I tried your suggestion but it still does'nt work.

**Comment by [phil333](https://answers.ros.org/users/21017/phil333/) on 2017-10-13**:
whenever you open a new terminal, the code in your ~/.bashrc file is executed. My bashrc file contains `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` and `source /home/username/catkin_ws/devel/setup.sh`  Did your run catkin_make before opening a new consol. Is ther a CATKIN_IGNORE in your node maybe?

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-10-13**:
After running `source /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, try to run `rospack profile`, maybe this will solve your problem.

If you just type `roscd && pwd`, what is the output?

Is your package printed if you run `rospack list| grep YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE`?

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-24**:
Hi Ruben.Sorry to reply you solate. After trying the command `rospack profile` it worked.But if I create new package, should I execute the command `rospack profile` every time?

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-10-24**:
Hi @tengfei,
I've added as an answer because the comments are limited in size.
In summary, YES, every time I create a new package, I run `rospack profile` to make sure it will be find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @tengfei

Even if you add `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` to your `~/.bashrc` file, it only will be automatically executed when you open a shell.

If you create new packages, the `setup.bash` won't be automatically executed on the shell that is already open, then, what I do is to run the following commands every time I create a new `ROS Package`:

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
rospack profile
```

Probably only one of then would work, but I always run both commands to make sure it will find my recent created packages, messages, etc.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0